# Getting an average from subquery values or another aggregate function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the SQL statement (SQL Server )

```
SELECT 
COUNT(ActionName) AS pageCount
FROM tbl_22_Benchmark
WHERE DATEPART(dw,CreationDate)>1 AND DATEPART(dw,CreationDate)<7
GROUP BY 
dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,CreationDate))
```

which produces the output

> **pageCount**
> 27
> 19
> 59

Now I would like to get the average of all those figures using SQL. Apparently nested aggregate functions like

> (AVG(COUNT(pageCount)))

are not allowed , and using a subquery like

```
SELECT AVG(pageCount) FROM
(
SELECT 
COUNT(ActionName) AS pageCount
FROM tbl_22_Benchmark
WHERE DATEPART(dw,CreationDate)>1 AND DATEPART(dw,CreationDate)<7
GROUP BY 
dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,CreationDate))
)
```

gets me just an error message *Incorrect syntax near ')'.*

How can I get the average of the pageCount rows?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I can't see your whole query as it doesn't seem to have posted correctly.

However, I believe your problem is purely a lack of a name for your derived table / nested subquery.

Give it an alias, such as MyTable in this example

```
SELECT
    AVG(pageCount)
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        COUNT(ActionName) AS pageCount
    FROM
        tbl_22_Benchmark
) MyTable
```

Comment: Apparently the lesser than character &lt; has to be written as a HTML entity. I had written all the code there, but this prevented the rest of the code showing.

Thanks, this seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 8):

Your subquery should have an alias, like in this

```
SELECT AVG(pageCount) FROM
(
SELECT 
COUNT(ActionName) AS pageCount
FROM tbl_22_Benchmark
WHERE DATEPART(dw,CreationDate)>1 AND DATEPART(dw,CreationDate)<7
GROUP BY 
dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,CreationDate))
) AS t
```

Answer (score 4):

Add a subquery alias

```
SELECT AVG(pageCount) 
FROM (SELECT COUNT(ActionName) AS pageCount
      FROM tbl_22_Benchmark
      WHERE DATEPART(dw,CreationDate)>1 
         AND DATEPART(dw,CreationDate) {Missing stuff here } ) AS Z
```

Answer (score 3):

in your second attempt you're missing a ) and an alias:

```
SELECT AVG(pageCount) as AvgPageCount FROM
(
    SELECT 
    COUNT(ActionName) AS pageCount
    FROM tbl_22_Benchmark
    WHERE DATEPART(dw,CreationDate)>1 AND DATEPART(dw,CreationDate)
) t
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you shoud add condition on the end of query. For example:

```
WHERE DATEPART(dw,CreationDate)>1 AND DATEPART(dw,CreationDate) < 10
```

2nd, you didn't close your bracket at the end.
3rd, you have to name your inner query.

This should work

```
SELECT AVG(pageCount) FROM
( 
    SELECT 
    COUNT(ActionName) AS pageCount
    FROM tbl_22_Benchmark
    WHERE DATEPART(dw,CreationDate)>1 AND DATEPART(dw,CreationDate) < 10
) myInnerTable
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to calculate average from two different by using procedure **

step1:select first column from ut11 table

step2: select second column from ut12 table

step3:by using left join join this table

step 4:((t1.ut_1 + t2.ut_2)/2)as total calculate avg

```
SELECT    t1.ut_1
         ,t2.ut_2
         ,((t1.ut_1 + t2.ut_2)/2) AS total
FROM      ut11 AS t1 
LEFT JOIN ut12 AS t2 ON t1.roll_no = t2.roll_no 
WHERE     t1.roll_no= rno
```