# sql average on count result

Tags: sql, group-by, count

I got a table with the following content:
Order_item

| Order-id | item-id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 45 |
| 4 | 45 |
| 4 | 57 |
| 5 | 68 |
| 5 | 32 |
| 6 | 68 |

I would like to know how many items are contained in average per order.

I tried that sql query:

```sql
select count(item-id), order-id 
from order_item
group by order-id
```

that got me the following result:

| Order-id | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 1 |

And now I would divide the 6 items of the count through 4 orders which gets me to my result of average 1,5 items per order.
How would I write a SQL query to get the result 1,5?

Comment: Please include your DBMS (e.g. SQL Server, MySQL, etc.).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting an average from subquery values or another aggregate function in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394603/getting-an-average-from-subquery-values-or-another-aggregate-function-in-sql-ser)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divide count of all rows by distinct IDs and multiply by 1.0 to implicitly cast for numeric division.

```
select Count(*) / (Count(distinct Order_Id) * 1.0)
from Order_item;
```